# Increment SQL Server variable across multiple SELECT queries

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to capture and increment variable across multiple select statements:

```
DECLARE @count INT = 0;

SELECT parent = 0, id = @count++
INTO #tmp1
FROM ...

SELECT parent = id, id = @count++
INTO #tmp2
FROM ...
```

Obviously `ROW_NUMBER()` is no good here. How I can achieve this?

Comment: UNION ALL the queries?

Comment: not good solution because in my case union and recursion in general is impossible or will be too complicated.

Answer (score 4):

I think you can use variables and `row_number()` for this:

```
DECLARE @count INT = 0;

SELECT parent = 0, row_number() over (order by (select null)) as id
INTO #tmp1
FROM ...;

SET @count = @count + @@ROWCOUNT;

SELECT parent = id,
       (@count + row_number() over (order by (select null))) as id
INTO #tmp2
FROM ...;

SET @count = @count + @@ROWCOUNT;
```